Should I clean up completed tasks in a WithEvents collection in VBA when using a COM object (C# DLL)? If so, how?
I’m working on a VBA project that uses a class with WithEvents to handle asynchronous tasks. These tasks are managed by a COM object (a C# DLL) that provides the task-running functionality. I maintain a collection of handlers, where each handler represents an instance of the class with WithEvents. Here's a simplified version of the code:
Task Runner Class:
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents taskRunner As ComEventTest.taskRunner

Private Sub taskRunner_OnTaskCompleted(ByVal result As String)
    ' Handle task completion
    Debug.Print result
End Sub

Public Sub InitializeTaskRunner()
    Set taskRunner = New ComEventTest.taskRunner
End Sub

Public Sub FireEvent(poraka As String)
    taskRunner.RunTask poraka
End Sub

Usage Module:
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Dim eventHandlers As Collection

Sub InitializeEventHandlers()
    Set eventHandlers = New Collection
End Sub

Sub TestTaskRunner(Optional retr As String)
    If eventHandlers Is Nothing Then
        InitializeEventHandlers
    End If

    Dim newEventHandler As TaskRunnerEventHandler
    Set newEventHandler = New TaskRunnerEventHandler

    newEventHandler.InitializeTaskRunner
    eventHandlers.Add newEventHandler

    ' Fire tasks
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 3
        newEventHandler.FireEvent "Task " & retr & "-" & i
        Sleep 100 ' Simulate delay for async task running
        Debug.Print "Task " & retr & "-" & i & " is running asynchronously!"
    Next i
End Sub

Sub TestTaskRunner_MultCalls()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 3
        Debug.Print "New CALL SUB fire " & i
        TestTaskRunner CStr(i)
        Sleep 500 ' Simulate delay between multiple calls
    Next i
End Sub

My Question:
Should I clean up completed handlers from the eventHandlers collection?

I’m using a COM object (a C# DLL) to handle the asynchronous tasks, and I noticed that tasks may complete asynchronously.
As a result, there will be more events, each including multiple tasks.
I'm wondering if leaving these handlers in the collection could cause memory issues over time.
Additionally, I'm unsure whether cleanup is necessary at all.
If cleanup is required, what’s the best approach for identifying and removing completed tasks from the collection without affecting currently active handlers?

Notes:

Each handler instance wraps an asynchronous task using WithEvents.
The taskRunner_OnTaskCompleted event fires when the task finishes.
The COM object is a C# DLL that exposes the taskRunner object and its events to VBA.
I could implement a flag (e.g., isCompleted) in the handler class, but I’m unsure of the best practice for removing completed handlers dynamically.

What is the recommended approach in this scenario? Is it better to keep all handlers in the collection or periodically clean them up? Should I rely on any specific patterns for interacting with COM objects in this case?

As you have taskRunner_OnTaskCompleted, I would use that to clean up the task.
